# C compiler can't find function definition

Tags: c, compilation, linker, coderunner

I'm new to C programming and encounter this question:

Three files: `main.c`, `foo.h`, `foo.c` are in the same directory.

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"    
int main(){
    printf("%d",func(1));
}
```

`foo.h` declares function `func`:

```
int func(int);
```

`foo.c` defines function `func`:

```
#include "foo.h"
int func(int a){
    return a+1;
}
```

This code works as expected, but when I rename the definition file `foo.c` into something else, say `bar.c`, then `main.c` throw an error during compilation saying:

> LLVM ERROR: Program used external function `_func` which could not be resolved!

I know that the definition file doesn't need to have the same name as the header file. Why the linker can't find the appropriate definition after I renamed `foo.c` into `bar.c`?

More generally, how does the linker search for function definition? Search every `.c` files in the same directory, one by one? Only search for definition in the `.c` file, which has the same file name as header file?

EDIT:
I was using code-runner IDE on MacBook, don't know how the IDE actually compiles the source files.

Comment: How did you compile? you have to pass the object file to the linker  `-o ...`

Comment: @o_yeah Please edit your question including your compilation line. Have you tried including the two C files in your compilation line? Something like `gcc main.c bar.c`?

Comment: The linker  searches for function definitions in the files you told him to link. So probaly the way you compile/link is wrong. You need to show us how you compile/link. If you ise an IDE, you need to tell us which one you use. Also tell us what platform you're on.

Comment: Are you using this: https://coderunnerapp.com/ ?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the file name in the compilation command:

```
$ gcc -o main main.c foo.c && ./main
                     ^^^^^
```

Comment: I think he's using some fancy IDE, so I'm not sure he'll know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it's a good idea to compile manually in such cases.